# Redirect to my custom page which contain a content search web part is NOT working when i access the sites using the URL defined as intranet zone

Tags: 2013, development, administration, alternate-access-mapping, content-search-web-part

I am facing this problem inside my sharepoint 2013 on-premises farms. where i have added a content search web part, then i did the following:-

1- Inside the content search web part's display template, i am using the following code to redirect to the content search webpart page, when users click on an item inside the content search web part, and they chose to edit/display the item:-

```
var SiteCollectionFullUrl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
var value = i === 1 ? String.format("<a href='{0}&source={2}' class='ms-listlink' >{1}</a>", linkURL, property,SiteCollectionFullUrl) : property;
```

where i am storing the current url inside `var SiteCollectionFullUrl`  then i am building a link which contain the `var SiteCollectionFullUrl` inside its source parameter.

now i have implemented this inside 2 farms, and it is working well on one farm, while it is partially working on the other farm, as follow:-

1. on the farm which is working well. i have the following inside the alternate access mapping:-

   - `http://servername/` as the defualt zone.
   - `https://customerA.intra` as the internet zone.

now when i access the content search web part page either using `http://servername/` OR `https://customerA.intra` the redirect will work well. Where i access the content search web part page, and i click on an item title, i will be redirected to the item display form, Then if i click on close i will redirect to the content search web part page correctly, also if i chose to edit the item i will also be redirected to the content search web part page correctly after submitting the edit form.

2. While on other farm i have the following settings inside the alternate access mapping-

   - `http://servername/` as the defualt zone (same as the other farm).
   - `http://customerB.intra` as the intranet zone. (while on the other farm we have `https` and it is set as the Internet zone)

now inside this farm if i access the content search web part page using `http://servername/` the redirect will work well. but if i access the content search web part page using `http://customerB.intra` i will be redirected to the list default view instead of being redirected to the content search web page. so seems for a reson or another the source parameter i am passing does not have any effect if i am accessing the content search web part page using the intranet zone in the second farm...
so can anyone adivce on this issue please ?